# Delimiting full screen region

Tags: windows-xp, display

Is there a way to delimiting a portion of the screen where when having a windows maximized that this windows won't go totally on the whole screen? I have some widgets at the right side of my screen and I would like when pressing maximize from a window not having them hidden under the window.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for Ubuntu/Gnome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [DesktopCoral](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/desktopcoral/index.html):

> DesktopCoral is an unusual program
>   designed to "reserve" some portion of
>   your desktop which is shielded from
>   maximized applications..
>
> Essentially, it acts like an invisible
>   resizeable docking bar, which can be
>   docked to any side of your desktop.
>   This invisible dock acts as a barrier
>   to maximized applications and
>   essentially shields this area of your
>   desktop from other applications.
>
> Within this shielded area you might
>   put certain application windows that
>   you want to be always visible, or you
>   might put one of the many desktop
>   tools like a calendar or system
>   information component.

Answer (score 1):

Check out DesktopCoral it may be what you are looking for.
http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/desktopcoral/index.html